# How to use AppCompatActivity with MvvmCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-support-library

I need AppCompatActivity in my MvvmCross application and I don't know how to use it and keep MvxActivity functionality at the same time.

There's a library [MvvmCross-AndroidSupport](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport), but I could not find it in NuGet.

Is it available for MvvmCross 3.5.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indeed need the MvvmCross Android support packages. You can find them by searching for prerelease packages on Nuget. The latest available is 4.0-beta5

Comment: So it is not supported in 3.5.1 and I need to upgrade to 4.0, right?

Comment: thanks again for help, I tried to follow your suggestion and faced problems with SQLite plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352520/mvvmcross-4-and-wpf-sqlite-plugin - could you please give an advise there?