# MvvmCross 4 and WPF SQLite plugin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

In MvvmCross 4.0.0 the Community SQLite plugin has been replaced with new SQLite-PCL plugin (if I am not mistaken).

It works great in my Android application, but when I tried to use it in WPF application I faced problems.

1. When package is installed from nuget there's no default Bootstrap file, therefore `Mvx` runtime fails to resolve classes like `MvxSqliteConnectionFactory`.
2. When I add bootstrap code manually I get error like:

   A first chance exception of type Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException occurred in WindowsBase.dll
   Version Unknown : Time 26/10/2015 08:53:16.232 PM: Error :   1.30 Exception: could not load plugin assembly for type MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.PluginLoader

I figured that runtime is not able to load assembly probably because it does lookup by appending .Wpf suffix to the name of the plugin, so it looks for assembly `MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.Wpf` or something like that. But there's no such library, in [repository](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/tree/master/SQLite-PCL) there's only `WindowsUWP` version.

What can I do to fix the problem and how do I use this plugin in WPF app?

Comment: You should probably add a project for wpf in the new sql lite repo. If you make a PR we could update the library for you to use after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF plugin added to MvvmCross repos, please check out the latest prerelease version.